# Why the Laravel helpers are deprecated in version 5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am a happy Laravel user and I love the Laravel helpers.
They are very easy to use:

```
{{ str_limit($text) }}
```

But really really don't understand why this is they way:

```
{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($text)}}
```

Why...?

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-8-deprecates-string-and-array-helpers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about an architectural decision of one specific framework. The decision has been blogged about and the answer to OP is both in a pull request and in the Changelog of said framework. It's a valid question but SO really is not the place to get an answer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The reason for deprecating them in Laravel 5.8 being that they add a
>   lot of fucntions to the global namespace and in addition to that they
>   migth conflict withe packages as well. Taylor Otwell has said in the
>   PR ,

- https://techanical-atom.com/laravel-5-8-deprecate-arr-and-str-global-helper-methods/

Answer (score 1):

From the pull request:

> They pollute the global namespace and they don't bring any additional value to the framework. They don't even save you the amount of characters that you have to type as in a bunch (or maybe in all?) of cases it's actually shorter to use the Arr and Str methods directly.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26898

If you still want to use them you can install [the `laravel/helpers` package](https://github.com/laravel/helpers)